# Making a bootstrap carousel's positioning fixed?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background, carousel, fixed

I'm trying to get my bootstrap carousel acting as the background in a fixed position. In my actual code I've got it to a full width and height that fills the screen, but it only stays in one place. I added 'position: fixed' to a class on my section containing the carousel so it'd float at the front and I was going to z-index it to behind the rest of my content, but it just completely disappears?

I've replicated the problem in this simplified example:

http://jsfiddle.net/v9FMw/4/

HTML

```
<div class="fill bg-green">
    <div>content section (scroll down)</div>
</div>
<div class="fill bg-white">
    <div>content section (further x)</div>
</div>
<div class="fill bg-green fixed-section"> <!-- fixed section declared here -->
    <-- carousel code -->
</div>
<div class="fill bg-white">
    <div>content section</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.fixed-section {
    position: fixed; /* controls fixed carousel positioning here */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the container `top: 0`.

```
.fixed-section {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9FMw/6/)

Comment: Amazing. I've been smashing my head against walls all day wondering why this didn't work when I could make it work on all of my other sections and missed the obvious hahaha! Thanks a lot!